# xcode 6.1 not loading proper iPhone 6 and 6+ simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I made my entire app in Xcode 5.1.1. Saturday I downloaded Xcode 6.1 to make my app on iPhone 6 and 6+. I already placed the proper launch images and app icons for iPhone 6 and 6+. (For this app i'm not using size classes because Auto Layout doesn't work for me in this app.) I changed some of my code to fit iPhone 6 and 6+ but the simulator clearly isn't playing iPhone 6 and 6+ because none of the UIImageViews moved according to where I placed them with the code. It's still playing the zoomed in version of iPhone 5. How do I load the iPhone 6 and 6+ simulators according to my code and not the zoomed in version of iPhone 5?

I was told to place launch images for iPhone 6 and 6+ and it'd work, but it didn't.

Comment: You can try adding a launchscreen file:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW1

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked for me:
From the xcode pull down menus, Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator (if you get a pop up error just dismiss it)
Once in the Simulator go to Hardware > Device > Manage Devices.
Delete everything listed under simulator.
Reboot your machine.
After that navigate back to Manage Devices in the simulator and click the plus to add back your simulators. Then the iOS 8 simulators will show up. Hope that also helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The old launch image asset doesn't provide the necessary support for iphone 6/6+. Remove your old LaunchImage item in your images.xcassets and create a new one. There will be additional options for adding the proper launch images for iphone 6/6+.